# java : get values from matrix

Tags: java

for each time I do an action on y , get values 0 and 1 from table.

```
String[][] columns = {{"col1" , "col2"}};
int[] values = new int[columns.length];
String[] y = { "TEST", "BUG" };

    for (int j = 0; j < y.length; j++)
    {
      //do some actions
      //bellow I need to get at the same time col1 and col2      
      table.getVal(0, columns [0][j])) ?
    }
```

I need to get value of col1, col2 on y1 and on y2 ? how could I use columns in the getVal to have the expected values ?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MatrixExampleDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[][] = { { 1, 3, 5 }, { 2, 4, 6 } };
        System.out.println("Row size= " + array.length);
        System.out.println("Column size = " + array[1].length);
        outputArray(array);
    }

    public static void outputArray(int[][] array) {
        int rowSize = array.length;
        int columnSize = array[0].length;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
            System.out.print("[");
            for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
                System.out.print(" " + array[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println(" ]");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Check this also...................

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class CreateMatrix {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Object matrix = Array.newInstance(int.class, 2, 2);
        Object row0 = Array.get(matrix, 0);
        Object row1 = Array.get(matrix, 1);

        Array.setInt(row0, 0, 1);
        Array.setInt(row0, 1, 2);
        Array.setInt(row1, 0, 3);
        Array.setInt(row1, 1, 4);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                out.format("matrix[%d][%d] = %d%n", i, j, ((int[][])matrix)[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see the logic in your code, but general matrix operations would be:

```
String[][] matrix = new String[10][10];
matrix[0][0] = "1.1";
matrix[0][1] = "1.2";
matrix[1][0] = "2.1";
matrix[2][1] = "2.2";

int x = 0; // col
int y = 1; // row
String val = matrix[y][x]; // 1.2
```

Comment: I only need to get values of columns on y1 and on y2 and need to get these values after for boucle to use them for the other computation.

Comment: @lola, I've given a demo on *how* to operate matrices in java. I'm *sure* you can from this sample learn how to incorporate it into your own code.