# save get values using arrayList java

Tags: java

In my example, I try to get val(0) and val(1) each time.
After `for` loop I need to save my values to use them for other calculations:

```
  String[] columns = { "col1" , "col2" }; 
  String[] y = { "TEST", "BUG" ,"ENH" }; 
   List<int[]> values = new ArrayList<int[]>(); 
   for (int j = 0; j < y.length; j++) { 
      // do some actions 
     for(int[] v : values) { 
      //v is the array for one iteration, use it like this: 
       int col1 = v[0]; 
       int col2 = v[1]; 
        values .add(v);
}
}

System.out.prinln(values) =>gives : []
```

Out of `for` loop, my values are raised, how do can I do to get my values after `for`?
Thanks

Comment: I don't quite get your problem, but you should be able to access `values[0]` and `values[1]` after the loop. Just keep in mind that their values will be those of the last iteration (which btw is the same as the first iteration, since you're not using any changing variable like `j`).

Comment: I don't want to keep last iteration, my aim is to get all values of iterations after loop.

Comment: Is this a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567137/java-get-values-from-matrix?

Comment: @lola `values` is an array of 2 ints so it can only store the last iteration values. If you need from all iterations then you have to 2-dimensional iteration as in Sean's answer.

Comment: @lola: reading your comments and previous question on this code snippet, I recommend to get the basics on Java collections. Have a look at the Java tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the question either, but, here's my best guess at interpreting what the question is trying to do:

```
String[] columns = {"col1" , "col2"};
String[] y = { "TEST", "BUG" ,"ENH"};
int[][] values = new int[y.length][columns.length]; // 2D array

for (int j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
  for (k = 0; k < columns.length; k++) {    
    values[j][k] = table.getVal(j, columns[k]);
  }
}
```

Comment: when I set getVal(0,...) 0 should not change as it is 0 row of my table, I change want to get values col 1 and col 2 on each iteration and use them after loop : I expect to have 6 values

Comment: @lola Then use `0` instead of `j` as the first parameter to `getVal(...)`.

Comment: this is not working : outside the loop it gives :                out!!![I@9e7e94
out!!![I@4788f3

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int value : values) {
    // do something with value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure of 'table', your data in the int array 'values' should be readily accessible via a for loop:

```
 for (int v: value) {
    //use 'v' here
 }
```

or directly:

```
    values[0];
values[1];
...etc
```

However, it might simply be a language barrier here preventing us from understanding the true problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values of all iterations after the loop, you first have to provide a fitting data structure. An easy way might be to use a 2-dimensional array:

`int[][] values = new int[y.length][columns.length];`

However, I'd recommend using a collection instead (assuming the original `values` has to be an array):

`List<int[]> values = new ArrayList<int[]>();`

Then fill that in your loop, either using array index `y` or just adding a new array in each iteration.

After the loop you can then iterate over the result, like this:

```
for(int[] v : values) {
   //v is the array for one iteration, use it like this:
  int col1 = v[0];
  int col2 = v[1];

  //or like this
  for(int value : v) {
    //value is the value of one column in one iteration
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In your updated code you're not putting anything into the list.
Note that you still have to create an array per iteration, get the values from your source (IIRC it was named `table`) and put them into the array, then add the array to the list using `values.add(...)`.

Also note that the loop I added above is meant to read the values later, it doesn't show you how to fill the list in the first place.

Comment: I tried with LIst inside first loop, but the value is empty [] after loop

Comment: @lola Could you post the code? Remember that you need to create the list *outside* the loop and fill it *inside*.

Comment: this is the code :String[] columns = { "col1" , "col2" };
int[] values = new int[columns.length];
String[] y = { "TEST", "BUG" ,"ENH" };
List<int[]> valuesInt = new ArrayList<int[]>();
for (int j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
    // do some actions
   for(int[] v : values) {
   //v is the array for one iteration, use it like this:
  int col1 = v[0];
  int col2 = v[1];
}}

Comment: @lola 1. please add the code to your question in order to get better formatting. 2. You did not just copy paste our answer, did you? I hope you did take our code and explanations as hints, not as fully correct and complete examples. From what I see (which is quite hard) your loop doesn't do anything usefull, especially it doesn't add anything to the list.

Comment: I forget the addto list, problem updated, but still give me [] ?

Comment: @lola As I said, you first need to fill `v`, the loop I posted is for reading it later on, not for filling it.

Comment: but I have added values.add(v) ?

Comment: @lola First of all, the code above won't compile since you create a `values` variable twice. Second you need to add something to the values array, you basically use it in an unitialized state.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3830/discussion-between-lola-and-thomas)